# Combobox not being filled after introduction of login form

Tags: vb.net, combobox, error-handling

I have the following code in my UC_Menu_Scout class:

```
Private Sub cmbScoutName_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmbScoutName.SelectedIndexChanged

        If loaded = True Then
            cmbReportDate.DataSource = Nothing
            cmbReportDate.DataSource = frmPlayerInfo.filterReports()
            cmbReportDate.DisplayMember = "ReportDate"
            cmbReportDate.ValueMember = "ReportID"
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub cmbReportDate_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmbReportDate.SelectedIndexChanged

        If loaded = True Then
            If cmbReportDate.Items.Count > 0 Then
                'frmPlayerInfo.myDataTable = Nothing
                frmPlayerInfo.myDataTable = frmPlayerInfo.retrieveDT() 
                dgPlayers.DataSource = frmPlayerInfo.myDataTable
                frmPlayerInfo.setReport()
            End If

        End If

    End Sub
```

And the following code in my frmPlayerInfo class (just the relevant code):

```
Public myDataTable As DataTable = Nothing

    Private Sub frmPlayerInfo_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        UC_Menu_Scout1.cmbScoutName.DataSource = retrieveScouts()
        UC_Menu_Scout1.cmbScoutName.DisplayMember = "ScoutName"
        UC_Menu_Scout1.cmbScoutName.ValueMember = "ScoutID"

        UC_Menu_Scout1.cmbReportDate.DataSource = filterReports()
        UC_Menu_Scout1.cmbReportDate.DisplayMember = "ReportDate"
        UC_Menu_Scout1.cmbReportDate.ValueMember = "ReportID"

        myDataTable = retrieveDT()
        UC_Menu_Scout1.dgPlayers.DataSource = myDataTable

        setReport()
        loaded = True
    End Sub

Public Function retrieveDT() As DataTable
        Dim Str As String = _
       <String> SELECT                 
                    Player.PlayerID,
                    PlayerFirstName,
                    PlayerLastName,
                    DOB,
                    Age,
                    PlaceOfBirth,
                    PlayerImage
                FROM 
                    Player
                INNER JOIN 
                    Report ON Report.PlayerID = Player.PlayerID
                /*WHERE 
                    ReportID = @ReportID*/
                ORDER BY 
                    PlayerFirstName     
       </String>

        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Using conn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(DBConnection)
            conn.Open()
            Using cmdQuery As New SqlClient.SqlCommand(Str, conn)
                cmdQuery.Parameters.Add("@ReportID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = UC_Menu_Scout1.cmbReportDate.SelectedItem.ReportID
                cmdQuery.CommandTimeout = 600

                Try
                    Using daResults As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(cmdQuery)
                        daResults.Fill(dt)
                    End Using
                Catch ex As Exception
                    MsgBox("An Exception has happened: " & ex.Message & vbNewLine)
                End Try

            End Using 'Automatically closes connection
        End Using

        Return dt

    End Function
```

Everything worked fine before I created a login form. Since then (upon a successful login) I've been receiving the "Object variable or with block variable not set" error on my comboboxes- saying they were now empty at the time of the form load event. Since setting the "loaded" boolean, this got rid of the error for frmPlayerInfo.filterReports(), however I still receive the same message for frmPlayerInfo.retrieveDT- on this line cmdQuery.Parameters.Add("@ReportID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = UC_Menu_Scout1.cmbReportDate.SelectedItem.ReportID. Again, saying the combobox (cmbReportDate) is empty.

The intial load event works, but the crash occurs on the cmbReportDate_SelectedIndexChanged event, on this line: frmPlayerInfo.myDataTable = frmPlayerInfo.retrieveDT() in the retrieveDT function.

If I remove the login form I have no such problems- any answers specific to my program would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how to get a reference to the main Form from within your UserControl:

```
    Dim frm As Form = Me.FindForm
    If TypeOf frm Is frmPlayerInfo Then
        Dim player As frmPlayerInfo = DirectCast(frm, frmPlayerInfo)
        ' ... now do something with "player" ...

    End If
```

No, this is **not** a good design because now your UserControl can only ever be used with the frmPlayerInfo Form.  If you're okay with that, then here's an example using your specific code:

```
Private Sub cmbReportDate_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmbReportDate.SelectedIndexChanged
    If loaded = True Then
        If cmbReportDate.Items.Count > 0 Then
            Dim frm As Form = Me.FindForm
            If TypeOf frm Is frmPlayerInfo Then
                Dim player As frmPlayerInfo = DirectCast(frm, frmPlayerInfo)
                ' ... now do something with "player" ...
                player.myDataTable = player.retrieveDT()
                dgPlayers.DataSource = player.myDataTable
                player.setReport()
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer- the error occurs in the index change event of the combobox, the form has already loaded at this point. The comboboxes are filled, but when I make a new selection, they are said to have no items

Comment: Where are all of these comboboxes located (which forms)?  I see you using **Form Names** in front of them, but cannot tell if these are actual form references to instances you've created, or if you're using the **Default Instances** of the forms.  When you display the forms, if you're using `New` then that will be a different instance than the one your referenced previously using just the name of the form (the default instance).  If that is the case then you either need to display the default instance (don't create an instance with `New`), or actually load the instance you created.

Comment: The comboboxes are located in my user control UC_Menu_Scout, which is a part of frmPlayerInfo. When the user has logged in, frmPlayerInfo loads- no crashes at this point due to the "loaded" boolean. If I make a selection from cmbScoutName (which is filled with two items) the error occurs

Comment: In your UserControl, you're using `frmPlayerInfo.XXX` which is accessing the default instance of the Form; this might not be the same instance that is being displayed on the screen.  Since your problem started when you added a Login form, you probably changed the "Startup object" in Project --> Properties to the Login form?  In your UC, use [FindForm](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.findform(v=vs.110).aspx) to get a reference to the form.  You'll have to cast the return of that to frmPlayerInfo with either CType() or DirectCast().

Comment: Yes that's correct- I changed the startup object to my login form. I'm not familiar with FindForm, should I be referencing frmPlayerInfo in the UC?